# Deploy ios buid using Self hosted machine

Tags: ios, flutter, github, github-actions, fastlane

I'm using a self-hosted macOS runner to build and deploy my iOS app to TestFlight. The build process fails during compilation and linking when interacting with AWS services.
Facing these issues:

```
Linking ClientRuntime.o
▸ Linking AWSClientRuntime.o
▸ Linking AWSTranslate.o
▸ Linking AWSTranscribeStreaming.o
▸ Linking AWSPolly.o
▸ Linking AWSPluginsCore.o

❌  /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axwsorderkhjqlbrxkrsavfyybbu/SourcePackages/checkouts/amplify-swift/AmplifyPlugins/DataStore/Sources/AWSDataStorePlugin/Storage/CascadeDeleteOperation.swift:164:50: reference to property 'modelSchema' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit

        logMessage("[CascadeDelete.1] Deleting \(modelSchema.name) with identifiers: \(modelIds)")
                            ^



❌  /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axwsorderkhjqlbrxkrsavfyybbu/SourcePackages/checkouts/amplify-swift/AmplifyPlugins/DataStore/Sources/AWSDataStorePlugin/Storage/CascadeDeleteOperation.swift:263:73: reference to property 'modelSchema' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit

                logMessage("[CascadeDelete.3] Local cascade delete of \(modelSchema.name) successful!")
                    

                         ^
```

Build environment :

[image]

Fastlane Summary:
[image]